# how to install plpythonu extension on postgresql 9.3 ubuntu

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgresql-extensions

I had Postgresql 9.3 server on ubuntu installed, but

```
create extension plpythonu
```

fail with the error:

```
ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

SQL state: 58P01

Postgresql is installed using ubuntu package management system

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

the output of

```
SELECT * FROM pg_language;
```

is

```
internal, c, sql, plpgsql
```

How can I extend the postgresql so that I can use python ?

Answer (score -1):

For postgresql-9.3, you can install plpython by installing the package postgresql-plpython.